# The CSS style of flask web development:development web applications with Python

Tags: python, web, flask

I am a new hand, I play in the book, but in the eleventh chapter I encounter a CSS problem. [image: The Problem]

So I decided to download the author's code and copy the `style.css` and `_posts.html` to my project, but it doesn't solve the problem. This is a copy of `css.style` and `_posts.html`:

```css
.profile-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
}
.profile-header {
    min-height: 260px;
    margin-left: 280px;
}
ul.posts {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
ul.posts li.post {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
ul.posts li.post:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
div.post-date {
    float: right;
}
div.post-author {
    font-weight: bold;
}
div.post-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
}
div.post-content {
    margin-left: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
}
div.pagination {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="posts">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <li class="post">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="{{ url_for('.user', username=post.author.username) }}">
                <img class="img-rounded profile-thumbnail" src="{{ post.author.gravatar(size=40) }}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-date">{{ moment(post.timestamp).fromNow() }}</div>
            <div class="post-author"><a href="{{ url_for('.user', username=post.author.username) }}">{{ post.author.username }}</a></div>
            <div class="post-body">{{ post.body }}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: how i to make the date and author to right?

Comment: Have you inspect your page and try to debug with your browser?

Comment: thanks to  you, i see Developer options there is a lack of something，the css.style only have .profile-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
}
.profile-header {
    min-height: 260px;
    margin-left: 280px;
}

Comment: i solve the problem，clean the brower caching is ok，thank you very much。